# Flex 4.5 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: apache-flex, visual-studio-2010

Can I use [Tofino](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml) (Visual Studio plugin for Flex development) to build IOS apps? Also do I need to download the Flex 4.5 SDK if I already have Flash Builder 4.5?

Comment: We are using flash builder and we have tried all other alternatives and they have lots of problems. It's better to stay with flash builder as these tools will always lag behind in time as compared to flash builder. Flash builder 4.5 supports almost everything that visual studio provides and also tfs everywhere allows you to integrate tfs with flash builder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I am also looking into tofino. If you already have flashbuilder 4.5 you only need to download the file for VS2010/VS2008 (without sdk 4.1).

I am not aware of a direct export to iOS but you can certainly import the project into adobe flash builder and export to air/ios from there.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you want to try it, is to use [Amethyst](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/amethyst-ide/Amethyst-Product-Page) that supports mobile development as well. It is quite a capable IDE built on top of Visual Studio.